# Installing the MySQL2 adapter for Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I am getting some errors whilst connecting to MySQL and the fixing of it led me to upgrade the mysql2 gem.

I ran this command to install mysql2:

```
ruby install mysql2
```

and now "gem list" shows this gem: `mysql2 (0.3.2)`

But I think it isn't part of my application environment still since the server gives this error:

```
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter)
```

I have RVM and I've used bundler to make a gemset for this application.  How can I add mysql2 to this application's gemset?

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'mysql2' , '0.3.2'
```

And this is my MySQL adapter version:

```
$bundle show mysql2
/home/agenadinik/workspace/udfr/mysql2/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.2
```

Also

$ rvm gemdir
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/agenadinik in PATH, mode 040777
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you cannot use mysql2 version 0.3.x with Rails version less than 3.1.x.
I assume you are using Rails 3.0.x or below (and thus you need to use mysql2 version 0.2.x):

Here is an example of how to set up a gemset and the Gemfile to use mysql2:

```
~/code/myapp $ rvm gemset create myapp
~/code/myapp $ rvm use @myapp
<<<<<Edit the Gemfile and add the line gem "mysql2","0.2.7" then save and exit editor.>>>>>
~/code/myapp $ bundle install
~/code/myapp $ bundle show mysql2
<<<<<Output should be similar to: /home/<your-name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-<some-version>@myapp/gems/mysql2-0.2.7>>>>>
```

Comment: @Zabba You know, my mysql2 version is mysql2 (0.3.2) which showed after I ran bundle install.  And then bundle show mysql2 command gave this message: Could not find gem 'mysql2 (= 0.2.7)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: @Zabba so I think my mysql2 is somehow not installed/not configured....right?  But it seems I just went through all the install actions.  CoNfUsEd :)

Comment: Please post your Gemfile and the output of command `rvm gemdir`. Also, what is the gemset name you created? Also, in which directory are you running `bundle install` (i.e. what is the `pwd`) and does the Gemfile in that directory contain the line `gem "mysql2", "0.2.7"` ? And what is output of command `rvm current`.

Comment: @Zabba just edited by original question with the info you posted

Comment: I see that you did not follow the steps I have outlined in my answer. Also you have not answered all the questions I asked in my comment above.

Comment: @Zabba Actually I went back and re-read your instructions, and tried them again and it worked!  Of course, now I am stuck on a new error message, but the one you were helping me with got fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Bundler, you should add

```
gem "mysql2"
```

to your `Gemfile`, then run `bundle install`

Comment: That didn't really fix things.  I am trying Zabba's example now :)  Will report what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

On Rails >= 3.2.0 you will see this if you are using an older version of bundler. Update bundler to >= 1.1.1:

```
gem update bundler
```

Once you have done this, update your gems:

```
bundle install
```